# Changing TreeGrid Dropdown icon

Tags: vaadin, treegrid

Is there a way to change the expand icon for TreeGrid in Vaadin?

I have attached the current UI of the tree.I want to add '+' as icon for expanding the tree instead of normal right pointing arrow and when the tree is expanded the icon should change to '-' instead of down-pointing arrow...

Current Treegrid with dummy data provider (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHUUI.png)

I tried various CSS settings to achieve this but none seems to work

Comment: "I tried various CSS settings to achieve this but none seems to work" - Please add your attempts to the question, so we can improve from there.

Answer (score 1):

They are not purposed to be changed originally. But there are limited options to customize them with CSS, e.g. if you want to change the caret to plus/minus icons from [Lumo Icons](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/icons). Add these to your styles.css. If you happen to have imported to font icon in your styles, then it opens more options by defining the `font-family` here too and using `\xxxx` code for that icon.

```
vaadin-grid-tree-toggle[expanded]::part(toggle)::before {
    content: var(--lumo-icons-minus);
    transform: unset;
}

vaadin-grid-tree-toggle::part(toggle)::before {
    content: var(--lumo-icons-plus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon that changes the icon and add lines between the parent and the children: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/explorer-tree-grid